# Bad access calling Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new to objective-c. I've taken classes in both python and c++, but am really interested in objective-c so I've been working on learning on my own the last couple of days. This program is supposed to compare files in two locations and add missing ones. A simple sync, although not all features are currently implemented.

The error arrises from the recursivelyGetContentsOfDirectory function. It is returning the error EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. Since it's not actually in the function I'm assuming that it's something to do with how it's defined.

```
   #import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface Sync : NSControl{
    NSURL *baseToDirectory;
    NSURL *baseFromDirectory;

    NSArray *filesInBaseFromDirectory;

    IBOutlet NSTextField *baseToDirectoryLabel;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *baseFromDirectoryLabel;
}
- (IBAction)chooseBaseSyncFromDirectory:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)chooseBaseSyncToDirectory:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)performSync:(id)sender;

void recursivelyGetContentsOfDirectory (NSURL *path);

@end
```

implementation file

```
#import "Sync.h"

@implementation Sync


- (IBAction)chooseBaseSyncFromDirectory:(id)sender {

    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    //Open the directory
    if ([openDlg runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSArray *files = [openDlg URLs];
        NSString *fileAsString = [[files objectAtIndex:0] path];
        [baseFromDirectoryLabel setStringValue:fileAsString];
        baseFromDirectory = [files objectAtIndex:0];
        recursivelyGetContentsOfDirectory(baseFromDirectory);
    }
}

- (IBAction)chooseBaseSyncToDirectory:(id)sender {
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];

    if ([openDlg runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSArray *files = [openDlg URLs];
        NSString *fileAsString = [[files objectAtIndex:0] path];
        [baseToDirectoryLabel setStringValue:fileAsString];
        baseToDirectory = [files objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}

void recursivelyGetContentsOfDirectory (NSURL *path){
    NSFileManager *tempManager;
    NSArray *contentsOfDirectory = [tempManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[path path] error:nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)[contentsOfDirectory count] ; i = i+1) {
        if ([[contentsOfDirectory objectAtIndex:i] isDirectory]) {
            NSString *next = [NSString stringWithString:[path path]];
            [next stringByAppendingString:[contentsOfDirectory objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSURL *nextPath = [NSURL URLWithString:next];
            recursivelyGetContentsOfDirectory(nextPath);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Non-Directory Found");
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)performSync:(id)sender {

}

@end
```

Comment: Although you apparently aren't seeing problems with the other methods yet, your `chooseBaseSync…` methods both contain bugs if you aren't using ARC. You assign `[files objectAtIndex:0]` to an instance variable, but you don't own that object. You'd need to either use a setter that retains the object or manually retain it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *tempManager;
```

You are not creating the tempManager

it should be something like

```
NSFileManager *tempManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
```

if you are not using ARC, you are responsible to (auto)release tempManager.

or use `NSFileManager *tempManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]`

Comment: Still some issues in the program, but it's doesn't have any fatal errors now. Thanks. I didn't realize that a constructor was not called automatically. I think I understand why though.

Comment: Objective-C has no constructors. NSObject's method alloc returns an instance, while `init…` initializes it. This is Cocoa specific, but not a language feature.

Comment: @dbaker90: A constructor wouldn't be called automatically in C++ in this case either. Notice, `NSFileManager *tempManager` declares a *pointer* to an NSFileManager object. If this were a C++ class, you'd have to do `NSFileManager *tempManager = new NSFileManager()`. That is roughly equivalent to the `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]` dance you have to do with Cocoa. The difference is that in C++ you can declare both actual objects (which *do* have their default constructor called) and pointers to objects, whereas in Objective-C objects are always accessed through pointers.

Comment: Since Mac OS X 10.5, Apple recommends avoiding `defaultManager` in favor of creating your own instance.

Comment: @Chuck That is what I thought. I've just gotten into this terrible habit of placing * without thinking about what it means since errors and warnings pop up from not using it. In C++ I always made the connection because I didn't use it every time. After looking at my issue I realized it was a pointer though.  Thanks for the info vikingosegundo. I didn't realize this was the case.